# Ghostly 'border' appears with border-radius in IE11 and Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

In IE11 and Edge (on Windows 10), the following HTML/CSS displays a strange, transparent border where there shouldn't be.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color:red;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }

        .menu {
            background-color: #5f6062;
            overflow:hidden; /* To contain floats */
            box-sizing: content-box;
        }

        .right-menu {
            float:right;
            margin:auto;
            padding:0 0 0 20px;
            list-style: none;
        }

        .spacer {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            height: 20px;
        }

        .content {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
            background-clip: content-box;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul class="right-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content-title">There shouldn't be a 'border' above this...</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ryf1unw/)  (You may need to **resize the window vertically** to see the 'border' fade in and out in JSFiddle — which is even stranger.)

[image: Screenshot of the 'border']

The most interesting part is that the issue seems to be caused by `border-radius`.  If I remove it, the 'border' is gone.  It will also go away if I remove some other element (the .menu div for example), but that is less of an option since I would prefer not having to mess with the structure of the site having this problem.

I've found mentions of `background-clip: content-box` or `padding-box` as a solution, but it doesn't seem to work here.

Also of note, while trying to reduce the size of my demonstration, I ended up with a code that showed the border in JSFiddle, but not in a plain HTML file.  This is the smallest I could get to display the 'border' both inside JSFiddle and a plain HTML file.

**Found the bug** in EDGE's [Platform Issues](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/6661381/) but still would like to find a workaround...

Comment: A "spacer" element, really? Replace that with a padding-top on the title element, and the problem vanishes ...

Comment: This could also have something to do with the `float` of the element. Try to specify a `float:left` or `float:right` to see if the issues subsides.

In my experience it's much easier to have elements like these have global classes like bootstrap's `col-md-12`. This makes cross-browser styling a lot easier.

Comment: @CBroe : The 'spacer' element was renamed for the sample code and actually contains a bunch of other element in my actual code :-)  
@BRO_THOM : Tried the `float` thing in the Fiddle and the border still appears. I'm trying to update the look of an old website which doesn't use Bootstrap and would prefer to keep changes to a minimum.

Comment: _"and actually contains a bunch of other element in my actual code"_ - yeah, I guessed that ... maybe pulling up the `.content` element by a `margin-top:-1px` or something similar could mask the whole issue, if at least the background of what the spacer represents is white as well ...?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like IE is rendering a transparent border to display the `border-radius` but picks the 'background' color further down the layers than it should (in my sample, using red instead of white).

So I went with workarounds...

On my actual page, two elements are having this bug.  For one my workaround was to **set the `background-color` of another element further behind the one with `border-radius`** and for the other to **set an actual `border` the same color as the element's background**.