# What is the problem with border-radius and internet explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

When I use border-radius in Chrome or Firefox I've no problem. But with IE 11 I got a huge problem when my div is resized.

On IE it render like that on resize :
https://ibb.co/ft2TB3r

But if I switch tab/window, inspect or scroll down (to not see my div anymore) and come back to it, it render well like that :
https://ibb.co/SdTWMgz

Here is my simple code:

```
<body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("body").on("click", function() {
            $(".div2").css({ 'display' : ''});
        });
    </script>
    <div style="background-color: black !important; width: auto; height: auto; margin: 0px 100px; border-radius: 0 0 500px 500px/0 0 100px 100px;">
        <div class="div1" style="height: 400px; width: auto">

        </div>
        <div class="div2" style="height: 400px; width: auto; display: none !important;">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Someone can explain me that? And how to resolve it please ?

Thanks!

## SOLUTION:

It seems like IE needs a border. So add this to the div with border-radius : 
`border: 1px solid transparent`

Fix found here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47869518/10345897

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A web page is just a set of instructions describing how a site should look. How it is interpreted may vary from one browser to another.

Here is a quick solution to query:

```
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("body").on("click", function() {
                $(".div2").css({ 'display' : ''});
              $(".div1").css({ 'border-radius' : '0'});
            });
        </script>

      <style>
        .div1{
          background-color: black;
          width: auto; 
          height: auto;
          margin: 0 100px;
           border-radius: 0 0 500px 500px/0 0 100px 100px;
        }

         .div2{
          background-color: black; 
           width: auto; 
           height: auto;
           margin: 0px 100px; 
           border-radius: 0 0 500px 500px/0 0 100px 100px;
        }
      </style>

        <div style="">
            <div class="div1" style="height: 400px; width: auto">

            </div>
            <div class="div2" style="height: 400px; width: auto; display: none !important;">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Hope that helped you answer your query.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! Your solution works but do not respect my architecture. I just found a hotfix but I can't explain the reason of the problem. Fix is in my topic description.